# Inform7: Z-Code vs. Glulx

Tags: inform7

right now I'm developing my first game and I am using Inform (1.2 6.31/6H98).
I have to use this Version because of the GerX Extension.

I'm using Z-Code and it works in Inform, in any Client and in any Browser.

But now I'm getting to the point at which I want to use extensions which are Glulx only :/

And if I compile the game as glulx only a white screen appears. In the Client and in Inform as well. But in the Browser it works!

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

---

I don't even know if it is a Glulx problem. Even this code results in a blank screen without any error:

```
"Testgame" by 18zehn

 The story genre is "Thriller". 
 The story headline is "A story". 
 The release number is 0. 
 The story creation year is 2017. 
 The story description is "sdf"

 Release along with a website, an interpreter and the source text.

 Include Basic Screen Effects by Emily Short. 
 Include Real-Time Delays by Erik Temple.
 Include German by Team GerX.


 Bedroom is a room. "Welcome to my Bedroom";
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates your Glulx problem?

Comment: @khelwood I don't even know if it is a problem with glulx. see my edit

Comment: Can you narrow it down? What if you take out the "Include" statements? What's the least amount of code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Even if I remove the includes, the screen appears blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running OSX 10.12 Sierra, this is a [known bug](http://inform7.com/mantis/view.php?id=1953) in the Inform7 OSX front-end. This has been fixed for the latest version of Inform7 downloadable from inform7.com, but there is little chance of the front-end being rebuilt for older releases, sorry. Your only options are to update to the latest Inform7 or to just live with testing by running the game in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to use this version because of a certain plugin. I installed Mavericks in a virtual machine to finish the game.